# Where can I find a good free password protected app/service which prevents access to any adult material through the browsers?

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome, safari, parental-controls

Where can I find a good free password protected App/service which prevents access to any adult material through the browsers?

I need to block all adult sites and adult content from Firefox, Chrome and Safari?

Comment: The only solution that fits your current description is to disable all your Internet access or remove "Firefox, Chrome and Safari". If you provide an exhaustive definition of "adult sites" and "adult content", somebody might be able to suggest a more fine-grained solution. You likely want to elaborate on "free", "password protected" and "good" too.

Comment: I believe you are just being anal now as everyone knows what I mean

Comment: There are firewalls that will do this, based on lists of "good" and "bad" sites, plus some word filtering.  They are used by some schools and libraries.  Don't know how good they are, or how expensive.

Comment: @TheLearner Eroen is maybe too strict but has a point. As soon as you will try any easy options you will see that these are not perfect. You can decide that it's fine in your particular case but are asking about blocking **any** adult content. The question as it is has only one answer: a very strict white listing or no internet connection at all.

Comment: Enough with the bickering, if you have something to add, post it as an answer or take your discussion to chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac OS has built in parental controls that work with those browsers (FF, Safari, Chrome,...). They can be activated in system preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Blocking **any** adult material is simply impossible since it is impossible to automatically classify or recognize it. There are services with blacklists which can be just a small approximation or software that tries to analyze the content but these are prone to errors.

You will soon notice how incomplete the lists are or how many false positives you get from automatic software.

The first time you will try to contact something like "Bus Express" and the software will tell you that the domain "busexpress" is blocked (has "sex" in it) you will see how poorly they work.

**Edit** As suggested in the comments by **white listing** only safe site you could be able to achieve what you want. Maintaing a list is on the other hand almost impossible unless you limit the white listed sites to small manageable size. Keep in mind that any site that could present you the content of a second site (e.g., Google) is potentially unsafe (for example the cached pages on Google)

Comment: To add to this: a determined person with some computer skills and with physical access to the computer could be able to bypass such restrictions relatively easily.

Comment: I disagree, it is quite possible through *whitelisting*. The result is an useless "internet", though.

Comment: @Eroen Yes and no. You could really just white-list a couple of sites but as soon as you include Google with the preview of the answers you could have give access to some adult content.

Comment: @Eroen: certainly not. With physical access the whitelist can be changed, ammended or ignored. If the whitelist is done at a router level or at DNS level, e.g. OpenDNS (one could just change computer settings to ignore them).

Comment: @lupincho I suggest placing the whitelist in a physical firewall (in a locked, *perfect* cabinet), using deep packet inspection and disallowing all unknown protocols. Assuming the whitelist only contains self-contained, trusted hosts I believe that would let you filter content to your heart's desire, barring someone bringing their own Internet access or ISP redirection. It won't be useful, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you sign up for an account, OpenDNS uses a free service that will block adult content.  You just have to set your DNS server to their DNS server.

Select OpenDNS Home from the link below:
http://www.opendns.com/home-solutions/parental-controls/

Comment: Does OpenDNS only work on the router or can I do it just on my mac?

Comment: OpenDNS only blocks dns request, not access to any content. It's like throwing away the map in the glove compartment before you lend your car to someone, to prevent them from visiting strip clubs.

Comment: @TheLearner  You can set your Mac to use OpenDNS as your local DNS server; that will override your router settings.

Answer (score 0):

"K9 Web Protection" is a free and light software which can be used to block websites of pornography, phishing etc. Here you can configure custom lists for "always allow" and "always block". You can get it at provided link. 
[website for K9 Web Protection](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/)